# How is min-width media query rule s mobile first approach

Tags: html, css

They always say that min-width @media rule is the way to build for mobile first, I have read plenty articles about it but i still can't understand how exactly min-width rule works> But the max-width is easy and lends itself to easy comprehension.

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {....some rule here.....}
 @media only screen and(min-width: 900px){......some rule here....}
```

my question  and confusion is: can one used both breakpoint on the same stylesheets? and how does it make for mobile first ?

I need a tolerable responses please, no down voting for those who enjoy down voting please be tolerable and nice enough to help put.

Comment: To me, it looks like you haven't done your research and ask us to do it for you. Please quote an official or respectable source for *"They always say that min-width @media rule is the way to build for mobile first"*. Who's **they**? Mobile first means: normal code applies to mobile. For desktop, apply overrides using `@media` queries. Both `min-width` and `max-width`, depending on what you're applying. Bootstrap has both, for example.

Comment: Maybe you are right, But thanks for your input, Its helpful indeed, "Mobile first means: normal code applies to mobile. For desktop mods, you add in additional rules inside." Really helpful pal

Comment: Mobile first means: develop CSS for mobile. When you're happy, open on gradually larger screens and start adding overrides using `@media` queries. Because you'll want to apply overrides from a particular width up, you will use `min-width` more when building mobile-first. And you'll use `max-width` more when building desktop first. From what you say, it's easier for you to write desktop first. So stick with that. There's no right or wrong here. The advantage of mobile first is it sounds better to people who have no clue what it means. So it's easier to sell. But, done right, they're same.

Comment: One advantage to using min-width is that you can use nice round numbers. For devices with at least 800px, you just write 800px! While with max-width you will have to write 799px and then hope that you won't get problems on hi-res devices that have fractional pixels.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed its true using `min-width` helps to make a web mobile first.

Let us take an example.

**We are creating a web that will scale to two viewports say 300px, 300px+ devices.**

*1)* using `min-width`

```
body {
  background: yellow;
}

// 300px+ devices
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

Here `background-color` is been overridden for `300px+` devices

*2)* using `max-width`

```
body {
  background: red;
}

// 300px- devices
@media (max-width: 300px) {
  body {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

Here `background-color` is been overridden for `300px-` devices

**Now down the line in your App timeline you need to support 600px+ devices**

*3)* using `min-width`

```
body {
  background: yellow;
}

// 300px - 600px devices
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
}

// 600px+ devices
    @media (min-width: 600px) {
      body {
        background: green;
      }
    }
```

New media query added to support 600+ devices, no changes needed in the existing style sheet.

*4)* using `max-width`

```
body {
  background: green;
}

// 600px- devices
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
}

// 300px- devices
    @media (max-width: 300px) {
      body {
        background: yellow;
      }
    }
```

Although we needed additional `media-query` rule to support 600+ devices, but we needed to change the global `body` `background-color` to support new breakpoint.

Now compare *1)* with *3)* and *2)* with *4)* ,
you will notice to support new breakpoint

for 1 to 3 we didn't need to change existing style rules, just added new rules over it.

but for 2 to 4 existing rules were modified to support new breakpoint

**Summary**

so `min-width` ensures future friendly and progressive enhancement (mobile-first)

but `max-width` leds to short-sighted approach and needs degradation (mobile-last)

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that designing desktop-first is a short-sighted approach. If you want the background to be green except on smaller screens, example 4 is fine. The difference between examples 2 and 4 is that the design has changed, not that you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @MrLister, there are different size of desktop available in the market, so desktop first will come with an assumption that users will be using certain size of the desktop width. Now suppose a page is developed for `-lg-` devices (1200px+), but the same layout will cause awkward stretching to elements for (1900px+) devices.

Comment: What if the same page is now required to render in some TV screens (waiting areas, monitoring software screens), and the same page don't need scrolls now for these screens. Developer will face the same situation, now in this case the Desktop falls between mobile-tablet-desktop-wide desktop-TV.
My point is a page should be designed considering one end first either Mobile or TV, but there is no uppercase limitation to screen size but there is to small size, where changes can be enhanced without making effecting existing layout . What if there come new devices with super big screen than TV!

Comment: use case of above scenario is very few, but you cant rule out the possibility that your page will be rendered in some super big screen. What if in future bootstrap layout will be supported through projectors!

Comment: Thank pal Shekhar, your explanation is very elaborate. But one question is that from your example since thesame element (the body is style) at both breakpoints its seems one will be overridden by the other, since  the first rule also hold true for the second

Comment: @pedroyanky indeed in both cases one will override other as per breakpoints. But the concept is about how easy is it to modify the style rules on the breakpoint, this is where `min-height` and `max-height` comes to play. Secondly, `min-height` doesn't ensure that your styles are mobile-first, but it ensures your styles in direction of `mobile-first`. the same can be made mobile-first using max-width as well,